# html5 input error tips

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am writting mobile page with html5.And there is a input element with required attribute.If input nothing,the error tip will show.But it appears at center point of the input in chrome v30.So my quetion is how to move the error tip to the start of input?

```
<input type='text'  required='required' data-tips='why here?why not start?'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var i = document.getElementsTagName('input')[0];
    i.setCustomValidity(i.getAttribute('data-tips'));
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: show some code please

Answer (score 1):

You can't, that's just how it is, browsers do render it differently and you have no control over the native looks.

In Chrome it was possible to change the looks using the various `::-webkit-validation-bubble*` pseudo elements, but [**support for this was removed**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050).

So if you want to change the looks now, then you'll have to suppress the native bubbles and implement your own custom UI, see for example  the demos for the [**webshims lib constraint validation**](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/webforms/1-webforms-lang-custom-bubble.html).